# Cannot manually upload photos to OneDrive anymore

Tags: onedrive, pictures, uploading

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 with Windows Phone 8.1. It was set to upload stuff manually to OneDrive. (I don't want to automatically upload any old file/pic I create! I want to select what I keep first.)

Since the end of May, nothing uploads to OneDrive anymore. It just stopped working from one day to the other without me changing/doing anything. One day I could, the next I couldn't anymore.

When I select images and try to upload them, it does manage to reach OneDrive and my pictures folders, it starts uploading, and then I get a message saying "couldn't upload" and something else that I can't read because the message disappears in less than a second. I tried uploading with 10 pics or just one, and I get the same error.

The other apps work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any pending app updates? Are you trying to do the upload from the OneDrive app, or from the Photos hub?

Comment: better use the webclient....I had given a feedback to onedrive team and they replied that its a problem with wp that needs to fixed (IDK whether they have fixed in wp 10